# Simple update check failing with SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl

I have a trivial "check for updates" feature in my desktop application, and all it does is basically this:

```
var url = new URL(urlString);
var conn = url.openConnection();
var stream = conn.getInputStream();
// Just read the latest version number from the stream...
```

When I run the update check from an application launched from my IDE, it works as it should (using JDK 15).

However, when I run the update check from a deployed application (an exe under Windows) it fails with an exception:

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at myapp.UpdateChecker$checkNow$1.run(UpdateChecker.kt:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I recently switched to the [Gradle Badass Runtime Plugin](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) to deploy the application, which uses jlink & jpackage under the hood. The JRE runtime it builds, is built from the very same JDK that I use to run the application in my IDE.

I don't really have a clue what might be wrong... other than perhaps the custom JRE that is built by the Badass is missing some component/certificate...?

I also enabled `-Djavax.net.debug=all`, and it spitted out lots of debugging information but I must admit I can't really make sense of it. Any particular string there, that I should search for?

Answer (score 1):

OK, the default/suggested Badass configuration was indeed missing a module. I got it working by adding 'jdk.crypto.cryptoki' to the list.